# Ruby data modellng has_many relationship two way

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I've got a question about a certain data model in Ruby. I've got a set of business requirements:

User can create many Workshops

User can attend many workshops

Workshop has one owner (user)

Workshop has many attendees (users)

The first part of this relationship is easy to setup:

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :workshops
end

#workshop.rb
class Workshop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

But how will i make the "other has_many" relationship from workshops to Users. Can i do something like a workshop belongs_to :user, :as :owner. and a workshop has_many :users, :as :attendees?

What are your thoughts about this? To make it worse a Workshop has a attendee limit so i need validations...

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a has_many to has_many relationship, so you'll need to create a new associative table to associate the relationships (lets call it attendances):

create a db migration:

> rails g model attendance

Then in your migration do something like:

```
create_table :attendances do |t|
    t.integer :attendee_id
    t.integer :workshop_id
end

add_index :attendances, :attendee_id
add_index :attendances, :workshop_id
add_index :attendances, [:workshop_id, :attendee_id]
```

So now you have a table you where you can associate many attendees to many workshops.

Now in your user model:

```
has_many :attending, through: :attendances, foreign_key: 'attendee_id', class_name: 'Workshop', source: :workshop
```

In your workshop model:

```
has_many :attendees, through: :attendances, class_name: 'User', source: :attendee
```

So now 'some_user.attending' will return the ActiveRecord relation of all the workshops some_user is attending, and 'some_workshop.attendees' will give you all the users attending some_workshop.

Comment: so how do I build a record such that it will show up in both some_user.attending as well as some_workshop.attendees? Is there a simpler way than doing both `some_user.attending << some_workshop` AND `some_workshop.attendees << some_user`?

Comment: @Eric That's how I usually do it if I already have the objects created (ie not working off of attributes)

Comment: @Eric you could simply do this @user.attendances.create(workshop: @workshop) and the same goed for @workshop.attendances.create(user: current_user)